# Need to be able to create a query with dates for headers - the range can vary

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am building a database that tracks time spent during the day.  I need it to display on a weekly basis, including days where no time has been entered yet.  So for instance, on Wednesday three hours were entered doing task1 and Thursday two hours were entered on a task2.  I want Saturday to Sunday to display as the headers, with task1 and task2 listed on the left.

```
       5/29   5/30    5/31   6/1   6/2   6/3   6/4
Task1                         3
Task2                               2
```

I'm playing around with different types of queries, but I haven't figured out a good way to do this yet.  Any thoughts?  The user will be able to cycle from week to week which will update the time period displayed.  Would a pivot table work best here?  I've never really worked with them in Access.

This is mainly used for display and new time entries would be entered on a different screen.

Thanks,

Comment: Check out Crosstab Query Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

ms access has cross-tab query built in.  that would be the easiest way to do it this and it would be really simple.

do you already have a table with data?  what's the structure of that.  If you're just starting the table can be this simple.

date, task1
date, task2...

Answer (score 0):

Your query will look like this:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Task.ID) AS CountOfTasks
SELECT Task.ID
FROM Task
WHERE DateDiff("d",DateSerial(2014,8,1),[TaskDate]) Between 0 And 7
GROUP BY Tasks.ID
PIVOT Format([TaskDate],"m\/d") In (8/1,8/2,8/3,8/4,8/5,8/6,8/8);
```

To run the query for a specific date, have similar SQL and replace:

- Year
- Month
- Day
- Date sequence

The last must be set this way to maintain the order when crossing 10/1 and 1/1.

Then set the SQL for a (new or template) query:

```
qd.SQL = SQL
```

Result will be like:

```
TaskID    8/1 8/2 8/3 8/4 8/5 8/6 8/8
Task1364                    1       
Task1367    2                       
Task1369                            2
Task1371    1                       
Task1374                            1
Task1375                    1       
Task1377    1                       
Task1391    1                       
Task1400                            1
Task1402                            1
```

**Addendum**

If no ID, you will have to concatenate the fields to make up a unique value - for example:

```
TRANSFORM 
    Count(*) AS CountOfTasks
SELECT 
    [Client] & "-" & [Plan] & "-" & [Billable Work] & "-" & [Special Project] & "-" & [ResearchID] As TaskID
FROM 
    Task
WHERE 
    DateDiff("d",DateSerial(2014,8,1),[TaskDate]) Between 0 And 7
GROUP BY 
    [Client] & "-" & [Plan] & "-" & [Billable Work] & "-" & [Special Project] & "-" & [ResearchID]
PIVOT 
    Format([TaskDate],"m\/d") In (8/1,8/2,8/3,8/4,8/5,8/6,8/8);
```

Comment: That was perfect!  Thank you for your help!

Now I have an additional question which makes this slightly more complicated.  The Tasks aren't as simple as "Task," but are instead tracked as a series of 5 items.  Client, PlanID, WorkType, Project, Task.  They are separated as each unique combination of the above 5 items.  So for instance, "ClientA - plan1 - Billable Work - Special Project - Research" would be a single entry type.  So this would need to replace Task1364 in your above chart.  Any ideas?  Perhaps I should start a new question, rather than continuing this thread.